# Django add parameter to url after login fails, in custom authenticator

Tags: python, django

I override the authenticate function to return to login but with url parameters if the auth fails, simply for deferent javascript behavior's

accounts/auth_backend/RoleModelBackend(ModelBackend)/authenticate()

```
# if user pass or email or role is wrong
   login...
else:
    login_url = reverse("login")
        redirect_url = login_url + "?" + urlencode({"user_type": role}) # role 
        return redirect(request, redirect_url)
```

mainAppName/urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
    ...
    ]
```

accounts/urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("login", views.custom_login, name="login"),  # Use the custom login view
    path("", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

i get error `Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: POST '/accounts/login/'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: POST '/accounts/login/'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`
on the redirect line in `authenticate()`

is there a better way to pass the frontend information other than url params?
else how do i ge this to work?

django 4.2